# android studio cannot resolve symbol "ff"

Tags: android, colors

I am trying to retrieve value of red, green,blue from pixel color value .So I need to perform some shift and multiply operation.But android studio notifying above error at following code.

```
clr=bm.getPixel(0,0);
cred=(clr & 0*ff)>>16;
tv.append((String.valueOf(clr)));
tv.append((String.valueOf(cred)));
```

ERROR:Cannot resolve Symbol ff at line no 2;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `0xff` and not `0*ff`

```
cred=(clr & 0xff)>>16;
```

`0*ff` is multiplying `0` with unknown symbol `ff` (since you don't have any variable named `ff` in scope)

While above code will compile and resolve your error, it is not correct code for reading red color value from bitmap pixel. Correct code would be

```
cred = (clr >> 16) & 0xff;
```

But probably the easiest and safest way would be to use `Color` class.

```
int a = Color.alpha(clr);
int r = Color.red(clr);
int g = Color.green(clr);
int b = Color.blue(clr);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to enter that values"?

Comment: You have entered multiply symbol `*`. But you have to use `x` instead.

Comment: I have added correct code for reading color values from bitmap pixel.

Comment: Which one is not working? What is your input value and what is your desired output?

Comment: i want to retrieve color of each pixel and calculate number of Unique pixel colors.

Comment: For that you don't need to get red, blue and green color channels. You already have that information in `clr`. Count the number of different `clr` values and that is it. Unless you have image with transparency and you want to count pixels with different alpha values and same color as one unique color.

Comment: Since this question was about compiler error, and that part is resolved, you should ask another question asking for specific problem you have with your color counting algorithm. Post your color counting code and explain what exactly you want it to do and how your code fails as much as possible. This is how Stack Overflow works. You ask one question at the time to get specific answers.

Comment: how i can get the color of each pixel in row only of bitmap image.I tried using getpixels method But it is not working

Comment: It should work. `getPixel` will return you color of the pixel as ARGB integer value. What is the value of `clr` you get and what value do you expect?

Comment: BTW, "not working" is very broad term. When something "is not working" and you need help, you should describe as much details as you can how it is not working. Without knowing specifics it can be very hard to give you proper answer.

Comment: here is the code: for (int i=1;i<bmwidth-1;i++)
                {
                   clr = bm.getPixel(1,50);
                   if(backcolor!=clr)
                   {
                       regionclrs[k]=new regionclr();
                       regionclrs[k].cred = Color.red(clr);
                       regionclrs[k].cgreen = Color.green(clr);
                       regionclrs[k].cblue = Color.blue(clr);
                       k++;
                                    }

                }
                 tv.append("no of regions" + k);`

Comment: it returning k=0 for every bitmap image.

Comment: Please ask another question with your color counting problem. It has gone beyond the scope of this question.